# A question in the proof of Herglotz Theorem

Tags: probability, random-variables

Herglotz theorem tells us, for every covariance function $R(n)$ of (weak) stationary random sequence with zero expectation there exists a finite measure $F=F(B)$, $B\in\mathcal B ([-\pi,\pi))$, such that for every $n\in\mathbb Z$, we have $$R(n)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(i\lambda n)F(d\lambda).$$

In the proof we construct a function $$f_N(\lambda)=\frac{1}{2\pi N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{l=1}^{N}R(k-l)\exp(-i(k-l)\lambda)\\=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{|m|<N}\left(1-\frac{|m|}{N}\right)R(m)\exp(-im\lambda).$$

Then we want define$$F_N(B)=\int_Bf_N(\lambda)d\lambda.$$

Finally, we hope to show that $\{F_N\}$ can converge into a certain distribution measure $F$ in a certain sense (maybe a subsequence converges in weak sense). But I cannot solve it.

Comment: Hi: If you go to this link,  https://gubner.ece.wisc.edu/,  then click on tutorial notes and then look at the paper: "derivation of fourier inversion formulae, bochner's theorem, and herglotz theorem", the proof of herglotz is at the end.  A few months ago, I went through the fourier inversion and bochner proofs because I wanted to understand bochner's so I can't say how clear or useful the herglotz proof  is but just finding a proof took a while so it's a start.

Comment: Actually, I was going through some of my old notes on bochner and herglotz and there's what I view as a more understandable proof in the last answer to the question here ( the answer by Zhanxiong ). https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322020/proof-of-herglotz-theorem-in-time-series-analysis

Comment: For future readers of this thread, note that, since this is math.stackexchange, some may prefer the somewhat more rigorous proof in the Gubner note.